# Get intracluster distances for k-means clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

Is there a way to get the intracluster distances, either from each point to the cluster center or each point to every other point within the cluster?

We have 505 entries of data (patients), each with 63 features (21 X, Y, and Z coordinates). These were sorted into 4 clusters and I am aiming to find the upper and lower boundaries for each cluster.

The code below should get the distance from each point to the cluster center, but I was wondering if there is a way to get the distances of each point to one another. I understand it will probably be computationally heavy.

```py
for label in range(num_clusters):
    dist = []
    
    for patient in range(XYZ_df[XYZ_df['kmeans_labels'] == label].shape[0]):
        dist.append(np.linalg.norm(XYZ_df[XYZ_df['kmeans_labels'] == label].iloc[patient,:-1] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[label]))
        
    if label == 0:
        dist_0 = dist.copy()
    elif label == 1:
        dist_1 = dist.copy()
    elif label == 2:
        dist_2 = dist.copy()
    else:
        dist_3 = dist.copy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question using scipy pdist function along with itertools.

```py
import itertools
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# Calculate farthest Euclidian distance between all the rows in cluster
data_0 = cluster_0.iloc[:,:-1]  # remove label column
d_0 = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data_0.index, 2), columns=['i','j'])
d_0['dist'] = pdist(data_0, 'euclid')

data_1 = cluster_1.iloc[:,:-1]
d_1 = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data_1.index, 2), columns=['i','j'])
d_1['dist'] = pdist(data_1, 'euclid')

data_2 = cluster_2.iloc[:,:-1]
d_2 = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data_2.index, 2), columns=['i','j'])
d_2['dist'] = pdist(data_2, 'euclid')

data_3 = cluster_3.iloc[:,:-1]
d_3 = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(data_3.index, 2), columns=['i','j'])
d_3['dist'] = pdist(data_3, 'euclid')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).